# Possibility of moving the ur10 universal robot with respect to the action goals being updated in its ROS topic "/follow_joint_trajectory/goal"?

Tags: ros, ur-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS developers & users,

Let me formulate my situation.

Aim :: To move the ur10 universal robot with respect to the updated action goals which are being published to its corresponding ROS topic "/follow_joint_trajectory/goal"

Things performed ::

- Played around with the tutorials provided in the ros-industrial package of universal robot using the website link (http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial )
- Checked which particular ROS topic should I have to publish a new joint-space goal. The ROS topic was found to be "/follow_joint_trajectory/goal". Type of this ROS topic is "control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal". Also, i had a look at the message sturcture of "control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal" using the website link (http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/control_msgs/html/msg/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal.html )

For the sake of completeness, the complete message structure of "control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal" looks in the following manner.

ros@rosPC:~$ rosmsg show control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal

std_msgs/Header header

uint32 seq

time stamp

string frame_id

actionlib_msgs/GoalID goal_id

time stamp

string id

control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryGoal goal

trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory trajectory

```
std_msgs/Header header
   uint32 seq
   time stamp
   string frame_id

string[] joint_names

trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint[] points
  float64[] positions
  float64[] velocities
  float64[] accelerations
  float64[] effort
  duration time_from_start
```

control_msgs/JointTolerance[] path_tolerance

```
 string name
 float64 position
 float64 velocity
 float64 acceleration
```

control_msgs/JointTolerance[] goal_tolerance

```
 string name
 float64 position
 float64 velocity
 float64 acceleration
```

duration goal_time_tolerance

- To be precise, I neglected the following parts of the above mentioned message while publishing the action goals to the ROS topic "follow_joint_trajectory/goal".

Field --- Object => Class (My interpretation of the message structure)

std_msgs/Header header => control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal

time stamp ---- actionlib_msgs/GoalID goal_id => control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal

std_msgs/Header header => trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory trajectory

duration time_from_start ---- trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint[] points => trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory trajectory

duration goal_time_tolerance => control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal

- So far, the ROS topic "/follow_joint_trajectory/goal" is clearly published with the action goals

Typical action goal published to the ROS topic "/follow_joint_trajectory/goal" and the message looks in the following way.

header:

```
seq: 0

stamp:     

   secs: 0    

   nsecs: 0

frame_id: ''
```

goal_id:

```
stamp: 

   secs: 0

   nsecs: 0

 id: 0
```

goal:

```
trajectory: 

  header: 

    seq: 0

    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0

    frame_id: ''

  joint_names: ['shoulder_pan_joint', 'shoulder_lift_joint', 'elbow_joint', 'wrist_1_joint', 'wrist_2_joint', 'wrist_3_joint']

  points: 
    - 
      positions: [1.4770721197128296, -2.000670909881592, 1.7188003063201904, -2.132617950439453, -1.6139060258865356, -0.28640851378440857]

      velocities: [1.4770721197128296, -2.000670909881592, 1.7188003063201904, -2.132617950439453, -1.6139060258865356, -0.28640851378440857]

      accelerations: [0.7385360598564148, -1.000335454940796, 0.8594001531600952, -1.0663089752197266, -0.8069530129432678, -0.14320425689220428]

      effort: []

      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 0
    - 

      positions: [1.9598301649093628, -1.015956163406372, 1.7667968273162842, -2.3582887649536133, -1.60133957862854, -0.4801400899887085]

      velocities: [1.9598301649093628, -1.015956163406372, 1.7667968273162842, -2.3582887649536133, -1.60133957862854, -0.4801400899887085]

      accelerations: [0.9799150824546814, -0.507978081703186, 0.8833984136581421, -1.1791443824768066, -0.80066978931427, -0.24007004499435425]

      effort: []

      time_from_start: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 0
```

path_tolerance:
-

```
  name: pt
  position: 0.0872664600611
  velocity: 0.0872664600611
  acceleration: 0.0872664600611
```

goal_tolerance:
-

```
  name: gt
  position: 0.0872664600611
  velocity: 0.0872664600611
  acceleration: 0.0872664600611
```

goal_time_tolerance:

```
secs: 0
nsecs: 0
```

ros@rosPC:~$ rostopic echo /follow_joint_trajectory/goal

Result :: Even though the action goals are published on the desired ROS topic (i.e., "/follow_joint_trajectory/goal"), ur10 robot doesn't move at all

Conclusion drawn from the result :: May be I have to fill the neglected parts of the message structure in order to move the UR10 robot successfully

Query

In the above mentioned message, it consists of two header parts where the relevant information needs to be filled. One header is dedicated to the "control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal" itself and other one belongs to the "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory".

Do I have to fill both the headers with relevant info (i.e., seq, stamp, frame_id)?

Has anyone encountered such kind of situation before? If yes, please give me your invaluable suggestions.

Thanking You,

BR,

Sriniwas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213800/possibility-of-moving-the-ur10-universal-robot-with-respect-to-the-action-goals-being-updated-in-its-ros-topic-%22/follow_joint_trajectory/goal%22?/) by [Sriniwas](https://answers.ros.org/users/22441/sriniwas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-01**:
Hi I'm also facing some problems with moving the ur10. I have one question though, are you using the position of joints to move? why not put a final position for say the end effector the make the robot move in order to get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem regarding why the ur10 robot was not moving.

The conclusion which i stated before is right. The action goals which i am publishing in the first place has to be filled with relevant **header** info, **stamp** info of *goal_id* and **time_from_start** of the trajectory field present within the *goal* object of the action goal itself.

The thing which was really missing was the actionlib::SimpleActionCleint interface which is required to send the goal to the ur10 robot (here the ur10 robot acts like a server). I referred to this link [Moving the arm using the Joint Trajectory Action](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action#The_trajectory_message) to realize how to move the ur10 arm.

If anyone is facing a similar problem, please let me know.

BR,

Sriniwas

---

Originally posted by [Sriniwas](https://answers.ros.org/users/22441/sriniwas/) with karma: 26 on 2015-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [semmas](https://answers.ros.org/users/23712/semmas/) on 2015-08-28**:
Hi, I'm also face the similar problem. Can you please share your file because I'm also using the same model UR10?

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-08-31**:
Also, all of your waypoints have zero `time_from_start`. This field represents the time relative to the trajectory start at which the waypoint should be reached. Trajectory start time is given by the `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory` header timestamp. Zero timestamp (default) means start immediately

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-05**:
Hi, I'm facing a similar problem. Can you please contact me: juantelo95@gmail.com
I'm facing problems with the structure of the message

**Comment by [_suresh](https://answers.ros.org/users/37739/_suresh/) on 2018-09-25**:
hi, i am also facing similar problem with the message structure. i am also trying to publish message to the jointTrajectory to move the robot.Thank you. please contact me at faltukaacco@gmail.com or if there is any other way to contact you regarding this problem.